# MQTT client re-using for publish / subscribe

Tags: java, mqtt

I have an web server which is getting a lot of messages to the same topic and is returning response messages to another topic.

I am currently re-using the same MQTT client instance both for the callback and for sending the response messages by keeping the MQTT client connected all the time.

However, after one cycle of receiving a message and sending a response, I am able to receive another message but cannot send the response - I have to restart the application server.

Is it a good approach to have a single MQTTclient instance? Is it OK to keep it connected all the time? What's the best approach for this kind of requirement?

Here is my code:

```
public static void registerCallBack(String topicName, String userName,
        String password, String clientId, MqttCallback callback,
        MqttClient client) {
    MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
    options.setCleanSession(true);
    options.setKeepAliveInterval(30);
    options.setUserName(userName);
    options.setPassword(password.toCharArray());

    // Connect to Broker
    try {
        options.setSocketFactory(SslUtil.getSocketFactory(
                ManagerProps.MQTT_BROKER_CA_FILE.getValue(), ""));

        client.setCallback(callback);
        client.connect(options);
        client.subscribe(topicName, 0);
        log.info("successfuly registered callback to topic " + topicName);
    } catch (MqttException me) {
        log.error("MqttException, " + me);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception, " + e);
    }
}

public static String publishMessage(MqttClient client, String message,
        String topic, String userName, String password) {
    MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
    options.setCleanSession(true);
    options.setKeepAliveInterval(30);
    options.setUserName(userName);
    options.setPassword(password.toCharArray());

    try {
        MqttMessage msg = new MqttMessage();
        msg.setPayload(message.getBytes());
        client.publish(topic, msg);
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        log.error("MqttException, " + e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Exception, " + e);
    }

    return message;
}
```

Comment: Could you add some details on why you're not able to send - exceptions, block on publish, other?

Comment: It's definitely fine to have a single instance and definitely ok to have it connected all of the time. I can't help with the code though.

Comment: @Anders That's the weird thing about it - there is no exception or message what so ever. when I dubug it, I can clearly see the publish() being executed without any exception, but nothing happens...

Comment: Perhaps you need to step into the MQTT code and/or attach a network sniffer. It's a little hard to understand your code flow from the snippet, but you do realize that the `MqttConnectOptions` in `publishMessage()` isn't used at all? And why `static` methods? Try without SSL first?

Comment: @Anders I managed to get some logs from the MQTT broker and it looks like the  message is being sent to the broker after all... so I guess my problem is with the client of this message. By the way thanks for the notice of the unused `MqttConnectOptions`. What's wrong with `static` methods?

Comment: Sounds good. Nothing wrong with static methods per se if used right, and you're aware of the one-per-class/one-per-object dogma.

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing something similar, and got this to work:

```
final CallbackConnection connection = mqtt.callbackConnection();
    connection.listener(new org.fusesource.mqtt.client.Listener() {

        public void onConnected() {
        }
        public void onDisconnected() {
        }
        public void onFailure(Throwable value) {
            value.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-2);
        }
        public void onPublish(UTF8Buffer topic, Buffer msg, Runnable ack) {
            String body = msg.utf8().toString();
            if( body.startsWith("REPLY: ")) {     
                // Don't reply to your own reply             
                System.out.println("Replied");
                System.out.println("");
            } else {                    
              try{            
              byte[] reply = "REPLY: Hello Back".getBytes();
              connection.publish(destination, reply, QoS.AT_MOST_ONCE, true, null)  ;
              msg.clear();
            }catch (Exception e){
               e.printStackTrace();
            }  
            }
        }
    });
```